# Issue with bending mesh by using armature

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers, armature

I'm a very new in Blender.
I'm modifying Universal studion template from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzzKW8qAkRE

I have a Mesh in the shape of the "O" letter. It looks perfect by it self.
[image]

But if it is connected to the Armature some bends appears on the letter surface:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried to play with some mesh modifiers. But no luck - just messing the model.
I guess it might be something with surface properties but I'm not sure which one.

[image]

[image]

Would you please be able to help me to figure out what is causing the issue?

Comment: how did you parent the letter to the armature? If you've parent With Automatic Weight, several bones may influence it and make it bent

Comment: Yes. According to the tutorial I’m using With Automatic Weight parenting.

Comment: So there are 2 possibilities, if you want your letter to be deformed by the armature, With Automatic Weight is a solution, except you need your object to have a good topology, otherwise you'll have bad shading. If you don't want your letter to be deformed; you could remove the Armature modifier in your modifiers, select the letter in Object mode, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone and press Ctrl P > Bone

Comment: actually as you don't show your topology we can't see where is the problem but it must explain why it bends badly

Comment: I do need my letter to deformed. Would you be able to tell me how can I show the topology?

Comment: just go in Edit mode

Comment: I do not have enought reputation to post more images. So I've uploaded topology to imgur. https://imgur.com/a/99jptI4

Comment: you topology looks ok so I'm not sure where you're problem comes from, maybe share your file (make sure you've packed all the image with File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend), use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I wasn't able to upload files thru the blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com due to file size limitations. So I've uploaded into google drive. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hovZZXlxTbk0OAymJmQQ3FC0yjbwwCES Tere a re 2 projects there: full and just with one O letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's say you want the letter to be deformed. In that case you can parent *With Automatic Weight*, your topology is good so it is supposed to get nicely deformed by several bones, so you don't have to reparent.

There are 2 main problems in your current file though:

- The *Subdivision Surface* modifier was above the *Armature*. Put it below:

[image]

- Your bones kept bending badly. So at first I tried to give some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode but wth? it didn't fix it. Actually it's because even though your bones are displayed as *Octahedral* you've segmented them (which you can only see if you display your bones as *B-Bones*), and you've only segmented twice the second bone, the one that mainly controls the letter. 2 is not enough, it will break the shape, so increase the value and it will work fine:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It helped.
Thanks a million.